# java Servlet Filter Location based settings

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

My application is visited from different countries and I am using a common servlet Filter (MyFilter.java) to control all requests. Is it possible to redirect to other Servlets based on country's visitor? 
        Currently my web.xml configuration is below

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>myfilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myfilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Suppose if user visits from USA I want to redirect it to  US_Filter.java , or if user visits from Australia I want to redirect it to AU_Filter.java, or if User visits from UK I want to redirect it to UK_Filter.java.  Is this possible from web.xml?

I am thinking of making Country wise configuration in web.xml like

```
country=US  (US_Filter)
country=AU  (AU_Filter)
country=UK  (UK_Filter)
country=None (MyFilter)
```

But I don't know how?

I require this because of different behaviour we perform based on countries for example their mobile no validation, managing users subscription services, etc.

Please provide me suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have the country in the URL? You can map a filter in `web.xml` by url pattern. Otherwise, you'd need to perform the logic you want inside `MyFilter`.

Comment: In the URL I can't have a country but jsp can pass it as  parameter.  How to map these in web.xml file ?

Comment: You don't map that in the `web.xml` file, but within your filter, with code.

Comment: @Magnamag.   But  this will have affect like  anytime new country is introduced I have to keep on changing this Filter.

Comment: I see. I'll post an answer that accomplishes what you want. Question: do you want to redirect to a  country-based filter or to a country-based servlet?

Comment: @Magnamag   country-based filter is the best  if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not possible to use your `web.xml` for this. However, you can accomplish what you want by coding your `MyFilter` class carefully, so that you don't need to modify it when adding a new country.

I see you're using Spring. That's good news, since `MyFilter` is actually a bean managed by Spring. This means that other beans might be injected to it. My suggestion is that you have one bean per country and one main filter that would be in charged of delegating to the right country bean.

Firstly, let your `web.xml` as it is now:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>myfilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myfilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

This will let the bean named `myfilter` be invoked for every request.

Then, implement `MyFilter` in such a way that it's country-agnostic, so that it doesn't need to be modified when a country is added or removed:

```
@Component("myfilter")
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    public static final String DEFAULT = "default";

    public static final String SUFFIX = "_Filter";

    // Autowire all beans that implement CountryFilter, mapped by bean name
    @Autowired
    private Map<String, CountryFilter> filters;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        // Get country code from request
        Locale locale = request.getLocale();
        String countryCode = locale.getCountry().toUpperCase();

        // Format key to gey country-specific filter
        String key = countryCode + SUFFIX;

        // If bean doesn't exist for request country...
        if (!this.filters.containsKey(key)) {
            // ..fallback to default filter
            key = DEFAULT + SUFFIX;
        }

        // Get filter for country
        CountryFilter filter = this.filters.get(key);

        // Delegate to actual country (or default) filter
        boolean countinueChain = filter.doFilterForCountry(request, response);

        if (continueChain) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

This class is generic enough. You wouldn't need to change it when adding or removing a country. The trick is to use Spring autowiring behavior for collections. If you autowire a `Map<String, T>`, then Spring will populate this map with all instances of beans of class `T`, being keys equal to the bean names and values the corresponding bean instances.

Then, you'd need the `CountryFilter` interface:

```
public interface CountryFilter {

    boolean doFilterForCountry(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) 
        throws IOException, ServletException;
}
```

You'd need to implement the `CountryFilter` for each country, letting it be a Spring bean whose name matches the pattern `CC_Filter`, where `CC` stands for the 2-digit ISO country code. For example, for US you might have:

```
@Component("US" + MyFilter.SUFFIX)
public class UsFilter implements CountryFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean doFilterForCountry(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) 
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        // TODO Handle US specifics here

        // VERY IMPORTANT: you might want to let the chain continue...
        return true;
        // ...or redirect to US page
        // ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("US-url");
        // return false;
        // ONLY ONE of the options!
    }
}
```

And for the UK:

```
@Component("UK" + MyFilter.SUFFIX)
public class UkFilter implements CountryFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean doFilterForCountry(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) 
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        // TODO Handle UK specifics here

        // VERY IMPORTANT: you might want to let the chain continue...
        return true;
        // ...or redirect to UK page
        // ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("UK-url");
        // return false;
        // ONLY ONE of the options!
    }
}
```

Same for other countries.

Finally, it might happen that you have no implementation for a given country. In this case, you might want to have a default filter as a fallback case:

```
@Component(MyFilter.DEFAULT + MyFilter.SUFFIX)
public class DefaultFilter implements CountryFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean doFilterForCountry(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) 
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        // TODO Handle DEFAULT specifics here

        // VERY IMPORTANT: you might want to let the chain continue...
        return true;
        // ...or redirect to DEFAULT page
        // ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("DEFAULT-url");
        // return false;
        // ONLY ONE of the options!
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you solve your problem. I believe it's a quite flexible approach, it even has a fallback case. To add a new country, all you'd need to do is implement a new `CountryFilter`.

Comment: A quick question.  About this line  to get "filter" object
   boolean countinueChain = filter.doFilterForCountry(request, response);

Shall I do following?
CountryFilter  filter=(CountryFilter) Class.forName(key).newInstance();

Comment: @MadanMadan Ups, I missed one line there. I'm editing my answer right now. Thanks for pointing out that mistake. You have to get a filter from the map.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Another question now. Don't we have to populate  that filter map with keys and values?  How can a following get a class without value for that key? 
        CountryFilter filter = this.filters.get(key);

Comment: @Madan No, you don't have to populate that filter map. Spring does this for you with the `@Autowired` annotation. Just scan the packages where all filters reside and you'll be done.

Comment: Thanks a lot again!  I forgot to keep Component.  hehehe..  now it's solved !

Answer (score 0):

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/locale/java-util-locale-example/

please go through this site!!

Using that site i was suggesting you to add another filter so that it check for locale & redirect to desired servlet.

Comment: Using that site i was suggesting you to add another filter so that it check for locale & redirect to desired servlet.